# How can I add the glyph property to my custom component?

Tags: delphi, custom-controls, delphi-xe2, vcl

How can I add a glyph property to my custom component?

Vcl.Buttons has declared class `TButtonGlyph` but I cannot use it (Delphi is not seeing it with Vcl.Buttons in uses list).

Comment: What do you want to hold in the `Glyph` property?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`TButtonGlyph` is an internal helper class used by the VCL. It's not what you need. I suspect that all you need to do is to declare a published property of type `TPicture`. The VCL will automatically provide a design time editor and can stream the image to the .dfm file. You can use any `TGraphic` descendent, including `TPNGImage`.